How to make this while loop create a list of objects?
The following code is meant to loop through a txt file and create a list of recipes that each have a name, cooking time and ingredients, which are themselves put on a list
 try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("recipes.txt"))) {

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                
                name = scanner.nextLine();
                cookingTime = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());         

                // while (!(scanner.nextLine().isEmpty())) {
                //    ingredient = scanner.nextLine();
                //    ingredients.add(ingredient);
                // }
                while (true) {
                    checkEmpty = scanner.nextLine();
                    if (checkEmpty.isEmpty()) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        ingredient = checkEmpty;
                    }
                    ingredients.add(ingredient);
                }
                
                recipes.add(new Recipe(name, cookingTime, ingredients));



            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());


This should work with any txt file in this format but in particular this is the example file
(the code I used initially has the while loop that I now put in // comment, I updated the code based on a reply, but unfortunately that did not solve my problem)
Update: My problem has been identified and fixed, thanks to everyone taking the time to help me!
Pancake dough
60
milk
egg
flour
sugar
salt
butter

Meatballs
20
ground meat
egg
breadcrumbs

Tofu rolls
30
tofu
rice
water
carrot
cucumber
avocado
wasabi


The problem I have pertains specifically to the list of the ingredients and I strongly suspect the condition of the inner while loop is responsible for the problem.
So what happens is the list only takes in every other ingredient for the fist recipe. So egg, sugar, butter in the example. Once the loop comes around to the second recipe my overarching loop is interrupted and my catch informs me of an error: no line found.
My question can essentially be boiled down to:
** what does the condition of the inner while loop have to be for my program to work as intended? **
I have tried several things but the outcome is essentially that suggesting to the loop to stop once the next line is empty always produces the erroneous output I described, and other than that I simply have no idea how to control the loop to stop once the last ingredient is added and a new recipe has to be created.
As a quick PSA: I picked up programming only a couple of weeks ago and this is actually one of the final coding exercises of the Helsinki Java Moocfi that taught me what I know thus far about coding. So please be kind and consider my very low level of expertise, I suppose the answer to my question is probably very obvious and easy but unfortunately I am unable to figure out how to do this on my own so I would appreciate any and all help. Thanks in advance!

in the first loop you check if there is a nextline and then you pull the next 2 lines. Your nested loop tries to pull the 3 line and check if it is empty. This should be changed to hasNextLine

When you're doing nextLine() then you need to store the result in a variable, and then check if it is empty. If not, add it, if so break. Your next problem is going to be that you don't re-create the ingredients list for each recipe. In Java, you should declare & initiate your variables when you use them so inside the loop.

This while (!(scanner.nextLine().isEmpty())) { is the cause of it skipping every other line. when you call scanner.nextLine() you already read that line and the cursor on the file moves to the next one.

@MaartenBodewes I tried to do a while(true), get an extra String to store next line, check if it is empty, if yes break, if not make ingredient equal the String. All that did was give me two ArrayLists with a bunch of empty elements and an error upon trying to create the third ArrayList. As for the second bit of your reply, will I not run into problems if I create the list inside the loop? If it recreates itself every time the loop is run, should it not delete all previous contents? I thought its generally not advisable to initialize variables inside loops.

@JorgeCampos Thanks for clarifying that what I think to be the problem is infact the problem. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

@ndrone if I use hasNextLine the loop simply adds every single line of code remaining in the file to the list, which is not what I want at all

@Felix_is_coding regarding your reply to Maarten Bodewes, it would help if you updated your question to show the code you tried which does a break inside the loop if the line is empty. What you said here should be correct, but you probably made a typo. Furthermore, it actually is good practice to declare your variables in the shortest possible scope - inside the loop in this case. And no, you're not going to delete the previous lists, because you're creating a new ingredients list for each recipe - each recipe's ingredients list is independent from other recipes' lists.

@k314159 just updated the code! also tried ingredients = scanner next Line instead of ingredients checkEmpty but that produces the exact same issue that I had with my old code as well.. and about the variable declaration: okay, thx! Will keep that in mind. Is declaring the variable inside the loop required for my code to run? I always initialize my variables at the beginning and haven't run into issues with it.  Course talked about that if you initialize variables in loops you can no longer access them outside of the loops? Which is why you should avoid that.. that's what I was taught, anyway

"This should work with any txt file" - will fail if missing empty line at the end of the file; "the list only takes in every other ingredient" - that is not happening with posted code (commented loop?!) - it is more like having all ingredients from the file added to all recipes

"if you initialize variables in loops you can no longer access them outside of the loops" - yes, and that is actually an advantage. If you don't need the variables outside of the loop, you can prevent using them accidentally by making them inaccessible. For more info, see https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/DCL53-J.+Minimize+the+scope+of+variables

@k314159 hm, okay, fair point. I will have a look that!

There are a few problems with your code:
1:
            cookingTime = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());         

This first one is not really a problem, but a style/efficiency issue. valueOf returns an Integer, which is an object that wraps an int. Unless you actually want such a thing, it's better to call parseInt instead, which returns an int directly.
2:
            while (!(scanner.nextLine().isEmpty())) {

As many people have already pointed out, this is why you're skipping every other line. Once you've done !(scanner.nextLine().isEmpty()), that line has already been read from the file, and is now gone; you've lost it and can't get it back to see what it was that you've just read. There are many ways to do fix this; for example, as Asmir said in his answer:
String ingredient = scanner.nextLine();
while (!ingredient.isEmpty() && scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    ingredients.add(ingredient);
    ingredient = scanner.nextLine();
}

Another way, similar to what you said you tried, is the following. Unlike the above, it avoids having to call nextLine() in two separate places.
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String ingredient = scanner.nextLine();
    if (ingredient.isEmpty()) break;
    ingredients.add(ingredient);
}

And a third way is as follows. This one avoids using the break statement which some people say goes against the idea of structured programming:
String ingredient;
while (scanner.hasNextLine() && !(ingredient = scanner.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
    ingredients.add(ingredient);
}

There is no consensus about which of the above three ways is to be preferred. Each has its pros and cons.
3:
                ingredients.add(ingredient);

The problem here is that you are using the same ingredients list for the whole program, so all your recipes will have the same very long list of ingredients. You need to create a new list of ingredients for each recipe, and the normal way to do that is by declaring and initialising the list just before the inner loop:
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    ...
    List<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
    while (...) {
        ...
        ingredients.add(ingredient);
    }
    recipes.add(new Recipe(..., ingredients));
}

4:
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}

Sometimes, it's better not to catch an exception. Just leave out the catch block altogether.
If you don't catch an exception, it will bubble up to the caller, and then to the caller's caller, until it finds a catch. If there isn't one, it will print a stack trace and terminate the application. Sometimes, that is exactly what you want. A stack trace shows you exactly where the problem occurred, and is great for debugging. On the other hand, if you want to print an error message to the user (who could be a customer, etc), then it's better not to confuse them with a stack trace, in which case it's better to just print a simple error message.

Alright, that was very helpful, thank you! Code works now, with the help of your reply and @Asmir 's. I implemented his solution, doesn't use a break and seemed quite elegant to me. I didn't know parse int yet, thanks. I was only shown the valueOf command to retrieve an int value from a String. I don't think efficiency is one of my top concerns in my first few weeks of coding though, right :D catch block is there for the same reason, was taught to use it, not experienced enough to know when it's actually useful yet..

As already mentioned in the comments by using while (!(scanner.nextLine().isEmpty())) you are consuming the next line without storing it no where and thus without the chance of accessing it again. It is also recommended to declare the local variables in the loop. Try something like:
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("recipes.txt"))) {

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            int cookingTime = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

            List<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
            String ingredient = scanner.nextLine();
            while (!ingredient.isEmpty() && scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                ingredients.add(ingredient);
                ingredient = scanner.nextLine();
            }

            recipes.add(new Recipe(name, cookingTime, ingredients));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    recipes.forEach(System.out::println);
}


Thank you, I didn't know that, I can no longer read a line after checking if it is empty. clever idea to check if ingredient is empty instead. I will implement this!

@Felix_is_coding if Asmir's answer has helped you fix the issue, you should click on the ✓ symbol. This will indicate that your question has been satisfactorily answered.

@k314159 just did, your solution helped as well though, particularly in understanding why my list didn't work and had to be recreated with every iteration of the loop. thx!

With a few modifications...
void createRecipes() {
    List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> ingredients;
    try( Scanner scanner = new Scanner( Paths.get( "src/tet.txt" ) ) ) {
        
          // "hasNext" return true if there are more items 
        while( scanner.hasNext() ) {

              // at each iteration, we restart the list
            ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            int cookingTime = Integer.parseInt( scanner.nextLine() );
            while( scanner.hasNext() ) {
                String ingredient = scanner.nextLine();
                  // if we have a blank line, we push out of "while"
                if( ingredient.equals( "" ) ) break;
                ingredients.add( ingredient );
            }
            System.out.println( ingredients );
            recipes.add( new Recipe( name, cookingTime, ingredients ) );
        }
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
        System.out.println( "Error: " + e.getMessage() );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

